# Trying to plot a topographical contour map in R, but I'm getting an error: "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large"

Tags: r, matrix, contour, topography

I have two vectors, one being all my longitudes and the other being all my latitudes. My longitude vector has a length of 720 and my latitude vector has a length of 360.

In addition to these vectors, I have a matrix that is 360x720 containing all the elevations corresponding to a longitude-latitude coordinate point. I need to use `contour()` to plot my topographical map, but I keep on getting

> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large"

when I try `contour(lat_vec,long_vec,elev_matrix)`.

Any solutions to this?

Comment: try calling `dev.off()` and running it again

Comment: If that doesn't work, make your plotting window bigger or save it directly to a file.

Comment: We need code and data. At the moment you are just asking us to reconstruct an example without even saying what R plotting paradigm you are using. I will withdraw my close vote when you edit the question to include those items.

Comment: Thank you Gregor--seems like I didn't realize by adjusting the window, the error would disappear!